# Open SAP screen from ASP.NET aplication in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, sap-gui, sap-dotnet-connector

I have an ASP.NET application which deals with the SAP server to exchange information. There is a need of opening the relevant SAP screens in several occasions. I have managed to do it in IIS express (in VS 2012) but when I hosted in the IIS, an exception occurs, ("Start 'sapgui' failed").

Is there a workaround to achieve this in IIS?

I'm using SAP connector 3.0 (NCo.net 3.0.) to connect to SAP. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have all the required SAP tools installed on the IIS server? Where does the message 'Start sapgui failed' come from? Possibly you are trapping an error and hiding a useful error message. Try and find the real error message and post it here.

Comment: any *.rfc trace file written ?

Comment: @Anjana were you able to fix this? I am facing the exact same issue..

Comment: What we did was a workaround, since we couldn't have SAP GUI opened in the IIS Server. We created a simple tray application which is to be installed in the client machine and send a signalR command to it(tray application) from the server when ever there's a request to open up SAP screen. After receiving the command, tray application opens up the SAP screen in the client machine passing relevant parameters.